# Umbraco DropDown List

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a requirement to store a list of designers with logos and some bio information in my Umbraco CMS.  I created a document type called 'Designer' with all those properties.  I'd like to now create a dropdown list with those designer names  so I can associate it with other document types.  How do I create this dropdown?  I'm using the v7 of umbraco.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout nuPickers for Umbraco v7.  Should have everything you need.

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers

http://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki

http://www.nuget.org/packages/nuPickers

Look here for help with creating custom labels using macros
http://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki/Custom-Labels

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your intention is to let editors pick designers from the designers dropdown when editing content items in the backoffice.

If so, you may want to either use an existing data type called 'Dropdown' or create a custom data type.

If you only want the names in the dropdown, the default 'Dropdown' data type may suffice. Take a look at [the article explaining how to customize the 'Dropdown' data type](http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/fundamentals/document-types/customizing-data-types/documentation)

Otherwise (say, if you want to show the avatar of the designer in your designer picker), you may want to implement your custom property editor (designers picker) and a custom data type related to it. Then you will be able to associate your data type with any document type you want.

A couple of useful links in this case:

- [how to create a custom property editor in umbraco 7](http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor)
- [the demo which includes building a custom picker property editor to assign custom data to a document](https://github.com/perploug/UkFest-AngularJS-Demo)
- [Umbraco v7 XPathDropdownList implementation](http://www.netaddicts.be/umbraco/v7-xpathdropdownlist-aka-docr/)

Comment: I think what I am looking for is the XPath DropDown list, however it is no longer in umbraco nor can i use uComponents with umbraco v7.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The third link in the list (XPathDropdownList) describes implementation details of a datatype that could list all child documents of a specific node in the tree